# php preg_match from sequence of numbers extract 10 digits that starts with 514

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, extract, digits

from a sequence of numbers I want to extract 10 digits that begins by 514

Example 21345653235**5141234455**8987

With preg_match ***or any other php code*** I want to extract the 5141234455

I Tried this code

```
preg_match_all("/^514/", $contentNumbersFromURL, $matches)
```

Bu I get

```
array(1) { [0] => array(0) {} }
```

Comment: If it's a small string, use `substr`, `echo substr($str, strpos($str, '514'), 10);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove  start of the line anchor `^`. `^` matches the line starting boundary. Since there isn't a number `514` exists at the start, your regex got failed.

```
preg_match_all('/514\d{7}/', $contentNumbersFromURL, $matches)
```